# Can you manually "inject" drivers into a hibernated drive image?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, hibernate, hard-drive-recovery

Is it possible to manually inject new drivers and configurations into a hibernated Windows 7 drive image?

I have a sector-by-sector drive image of a hibernated Windows 7 install. It's imaged from an Intel SSD that is no longer usable. I've restored the hibernated image to a new Samsung SSD, properly aligning the partition boundaries. But now there's the issue of Windows 7 awaking from hibernation to a completely new and different SSD. My first attempt to to resume from hibernation led to a "Kernel_data_inpage_error" BSOD.

Macrium Reflect has a feature called "ReDeploy" which assists in the transferring of a drive image from old hardware to new hardware -- I'm wondering how one might do this manually by manually injecting and/or tweaking drivers/configs to help this hibernated image properly resume itself to a new SSD -- ideally, restoring the hibernation data, and not having to "cold" boot.

Comment: Is the SSD the only part of the hardware that changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hibernated data has dependencies upon the hardware installed at the time the hibernation occurred - there's no getting around that.